# Not able to scrape data from website using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I can't scrape data from this website
http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/hydro5d.html

I use Beautiful Soup to scrape data. But data `inside table in the website` not found in export file.

```
import requests
url = "http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/hydro5d.html"
data = requests.get(url)
time.sleep(20) 
print(data.status_code)
print(data.text)
```

How to scrape all data including table data on a website in to text or csv file.

Answer (score 0):

@joke mamub This is the final code.It works.Test it.

```
 import requests
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
 import json
 headers = {
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
 like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36',
 'Referer': 'http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/hydro5d.html',
}

params = (
 ('option', '2'),
  )

 data = {
'DW[UtokID]': '5',
'DW[TimeCurrent]': '12/01/2562',
'_search': 'false',
'nd': '1547209026513',
'rows': '1000',
'page': '1',
'sidx': 'indexcount',
'sord': 'asc'
}

url = 'http://hyd- 
 app.rid.go.th/webservice/getDailyWaterLevelListReport5.ashx'

  response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
  print(response.json())
```